# Page scrolling issue in zoom chart

Tags: scroll, zoomcharts

I'm using zoomcharts geomap in a div in my page. While I place the cursor over the map and scroll, then the map will zoom. I want to disable the zoom functionality and I want to scroll the page if I scroll while cursor is over the map.

I tried to disabled the zoom using the zoomcharts documentation below.

```
Interaction: {
 zooming: {
  enabled: false
 }
}
```

This helps to disable the zoom only but I want the page to scroll. any idea on how to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
chart = new GeoChart(options);

setTimeout(function(){
   chart._impl._map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
}, 100);
```